# rCharts-How to add axis lables and Headings to NVD3 chart

Tags: r, rcharts

I am exploriing rCharts. I got stuck while adding Lables to Y axis and Headings. I am new to rCharts.

This is my sample code

```
require(rCharts)
n2 <- nPlot(Hours ~ Month, group = "Task", data = cars, type = "multiBarChart",
height = 900, width = 1110)
n2$xAxis(axisLabel = 'Year and Month')
n2
```

Please help.

Comment: This is my sample code:> n2 <- nPlot(Hours ~ Month, group = "Task", data = cars, type = "multiBarChart",height = 900, width = 1110)
> n2$xAxis(axisLabel = 'Year and Month')
> n2 -- I still need to add Y axis and Headings to Bar Chart

Comment: I hope that you don't mind that I edited your question to make it more readable.

Answer (score 13):

*answer supplemented with title examples 2013-12-05*

I cannot remember why `nvd3` with `rCharts` does this but we have discovered this in this [issue](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/102).  The method suggested in that issue works, but using `margin` is probably the more robust method.  I have put a quick example together of both ways.  Let me know how this works.

```
      require(rCharts)

      df <- data.frame(x=1:20,y=runif(n=20))

      n1 <- nPlot(
        y~x,
        data=df,
        type="multiBarChart"
      )
      n1$yAxis( axisLabel = "Randomness" )

      #nvd3 draws the label but falls outside the bounds
      #so two ways to fix

      #best way I believe is to set the margin to allow room
      #nvd3 draws at -63, so something bigger than 63
      n1$chart(margin = list(left = 100))
      n1


      #second way as discussed here
      #https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/102
      n1$yAxis( axisLabel = "Randomness", width = 40 )
      n1
```

#### now let's add a title

There are a couple ways to achieve this.  I currently prefer using a script template with `rCharts`.  Here are two examples.  An `<h3>` element is inserted in the `rCharts` div.  The two templates live in [this repo](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/rcharts_nvd3_templates) if you would like to see how they work.

```
      #for a local template something like this
      #n1$templates$script <- "./chartWithTitle.html"
      n1$templates$script <- "http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_nvd3_templates/chartWithTitle.html"
      n1$set(title = "rCharts + nvd3 Power")
      n1

      #using some css style from http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/02/heading-set-styling-with-css/
      #put in a different template 
      n1$templates$script <- "http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_nvd3_templates/chartWithTitle_styled.html"
      n1
```

Comment: Wonderful! I choose second way and it did work. I still not able to add Header and I need your help adding help in Header with bold.

Comment: I am not sure if NVD3 supports titles.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate for your quick response.

Comment: I added two title examples above using rCharts script templates.

Comment: Awesome contributors!! Thanks again.

Comment: @timelyportfolio, This works very well thanks. I couldn't get it to work inside a shiny app, any ideas? Should I post a question about this with a gist?